# How to close websocket connection when browser tab crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

I have a WebGL application with three.js where i have used web-socket connection to communicate with other user. Normally when i close the browser or close the tab web-socket `onclose()` event is fired & web-socket closes automatically. But when my tab crashes or if i close only the tab(not the whole browser) with end process from task manager web-socket connection is not closed.

Here is a image showing web-socket active after tab crash:
[image]

This happen both in firefox and chrome.

Is there any way i can detect when a tab crash or close web-socket connection on tab crash?

Comment: How are you able to access `DevTools` or `Developer Tools` if the tab crashed?

Comment: I was using chrome and  i closed the tab process from task manager. Before closing the process i opened the dev tool and it was kept open after the tab crashed. In firefox i was unable to do that.

Comment: Only WebGL crashed not the whole tab.

Comment: In firefox it shows the tab has crashed. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/SPYdQ) is the image of firefox crashing. If i can detect webgl crash that will be okay too. Can you help me?